# Existe no javascript um operador de coalescência nula? Tal como o operador ?? do C#

Tags: javascript

No C# existe um operador `??` que serve para fazer coalescência nula, usada seguindo a sintaxe:

```
var valor = valorAnulável ?? valorPadrão;
```

Onde:

- valorAnulável é um valor qualquer inclusive nulo
- valorPadrão é um valor qualquer, geralmente não é nulo

O operador retorna o valorAnulável se ele não for nulo, e se ele for nulo, retorna o valorPadrão. É o mesmo que dizer:

```
var valor = valorAnulável != null ? valorAnulável : valorPadrão;
```

Existe algo parecido com isso no Javascript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

É possível obter um comportamento semelhando ao do operador `??` do C# no
javascript, usando o operador de **ou lógico**: `||`.

Existem entretanto algumas diferenças, e para isso temos que entender o que o
operador `||` do javascript significa.

```
var resultado = valorA || valorB;
```

é exatamente o mesmo que:

```
var resultado = valorA ? valorA : valorB;
```

Acontece que no javascript, praticamente todos os valores podem tratados de
forma lógica, ou seja, convertidos para verdadeiro ou falso. Quanto à operação
anterior, quando o valor `valorA` é tratado como verdadeiro, o resultado da
expressão é o seu próprio valor. Quando é tratado como falso, o resultado da
expressão é o valor `valorB`.

Devemos então entender o que é tratado como verdadeiro e como falso.

O que é falso:

- string vazia: ""
- número 0 (zero)
- false
- null
- undefined
- NaN

O que é verdadeiro:

- tudo que não for falso... incluindo os seguintes
- strings não vazias: "0", "true", **"false"** (é importante lembrar desse)
- todos os números diferentes de 0: 1, -1, -1000, 1/10
- true

**Alguns exemplos**

```
false || "texto qualquer"     // "texto qualquer"
"" || "texto qualquer"        // "texto qualquer"
0 || "texto qualquer"         // "texto qualquer"
null || "texto qualquer"      // "texto qualquer"
undefined || "texto qualquer" // "texto qualquer"

"algum texto" || "texto qualquer" // "algum texto"
1 || "texto qualquer"             // 1
```

Notou a diferença para o `??` do C#... somente se o primeiro for `null` é que o
segundo será o resultado, caso contrário o resultado é o primeiro.
Diferente do javascript em que o segundo é o resultado, se o valor do primeiro
for `falso`, `0` ou `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, a proposa de operador de coalescência nula do JS está avançando: [TC39 Proposal nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing).

Logo (ES2020 ?) devemos ter esse operador e o operador de navegação nula no JS, o que ajuda muito nesses cenarios:

```
someVariable.someProperty || 'some value'; 
// caso o valor seja '' ou 0, ira retornar o valor mais a direita, o que pode nao ser a intenção original

someVariable.someProperty ?? 'some value'; 
// neste caso apenas null e undefined serao checados
```

e teremos o operador de [conditional null](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) tb, ja disponivel no Angular 2+ atraves de template strings, em vez de escrever:

```js
if(someVariable && someVariable.someProperty) someVariable.someProperty.someFunction()
```

poderemos escrever:

```
someVariable.someProperty?.someFunction();
```