# Como colocar argumentos default (padrão) em uma função em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções

No R isso seria muito simples:

```
funcao <- function(x=10) return(x)
```

Se você chamar `funcao()` sem argumentos o resultado será `10`.

Como fazer o mesmo em JavaScript? E como saber se existem valores `default` na função sem ter que ler o código?

Comment: Eu tentei uma forma de verificar valores default, mas esbarrei num problema: Falso-Positivo, eu implementei o seguinte: verificar se o tipo era undefined no começo e no final fazia uma verificação no tipo novamente, se tivesse mudado é porque tem valor padrão, mas quando passava um parâmetro ela me retornava que não havia um valor padrão mesmo existindo.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com um um método para facilitar a definição de valores padrão. Se alguém se interessar, e quiser contribuir [Function.prototype.WithDefaults](https://bitbucket.org/masbicudo/function.prototype.withdefaults).

Comment: Achei uma outra forma de fazer, mais simples do que o que eu fiz, mas igualmente útil: [cjwainwright / withDefaults.js](https://gist.github.com/cjwainwright/4678359)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As outras respostas estão corretas no uso geral, mas se você quiser ser super estrito e correto, precisa levar a variável `arguments` em consideração. Veja isso:

```
// Função identidade, com argumento padrão 10.
function f(x) {
    x = x || 10;
    // if (x == null) x = 10;
    // x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 10;
    return x;
}

f()           // => Retorna 10
f(3)          // => Retorna 3
f(null)       // => Retorna 10. Epa! Era para isso retornar null não?
f(undefined)  // => Retorna 10. Também!
f(0)          // => 10? Tá de brincadeira né?
```

Toda função ao ser invocada recebe uma variável especial chamada `arguments`. Ela funciona como uma array (tem a propriedade `length` e pode ser acessada numericamente `[0]`, `[1]`, ...). Para essa função de identidade o mais correto seria fazer o seguinte:

```
// Agora processando o arguments.
function f() {
    x = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[0] : 10;
    return x;
}

f()     // => Retorna 10
f(3)    // => Retorna 3
f(null) // => Retorna null. Isso!
```

Você pode aproveitar ainda para acrescentar um erro caso argumentos de mais sejam usados:

```
if (arguments.length > 1) throw new Error("Too many arguments! Expected 1.");
```

Comment: Boa, depois dessa até excluí minha resposta :)

Comment: Excelente, programando e aprendendo :)

Comment: Apesar de não ser muito normal perguntar algo sobre uma resposta dada por aqui mas, até mesma para que a resposta tenha uma abrangência ainda maior, a definição dos valores-padrão de cada possível argumento deve ser definida assim, manualmente, um a um?

Comment: Vale lembrar que na especificação ECMAScript6 (Harmony) já é possível utilizar default parameters da seguinte maneira: function f(x=10){ return x}. Algumas referências: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:parameter_default_values http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/10/es6-part-4/#default-parameters

Comment: E o mais legal é que existem diversos polyfills para ECMAScript6 (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#ecmascript-6-harmony), inclusive com suporte para default parameters (https://github.com/termi/es6-transpiler#supported)

Comment: @Bruno, é bastante comum se perguntar esclarecimentos sobre respostas nos comentários, isso ajuda a melhorar a resposta. Sobre fazer tudo em uma linha só, não há muito que ajude. Você pode talvez escrever uma função auxiliar ou usar algo como o [args.js](http://autographer.github.io/args.js/) ou o [args-js](https://github.com/theshock/args-js) ou o [argspecjs](https://github.com/zefhemel/argspecjs). Variantes estão ai para todos os gostos.

Answer (score 19):

Em javascript que os browsers atuais (2015) usam teria de ter um `if` de alguma forma dentro da função. Mas no futuro, com browsers que suportem a nova norma ES6 já é possivel.

#### O que é possível hoje (2015):

Hoje em dia, com a versão do JavaScript que os browsers usam isso não é possivel. A solução a usar é verificar o valor dentro da função, como referiste na pergunta.

Por exemplo:

```
function b(a){
   if (typeof a == 'undefined') a = 1;
   return a;
}
```

Nota: O Firefox já está a implementar algumas das ideias de ES6 mas isso nõ é compatível cross-browser hoje em dia, daí inviàvel em produção.

#### Com ES6 - [*"Default function parameters"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Quando a nova versão de JavaScript fôr implementada nos browsers, como o Firefox já está a fazer neste caso, a solução será (segundo o que as especificações da [ECMAscript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions)) como é no PHP (e que o Firefox já está a aplicar).

```
function b (a = 1) {
   return a;
}
console.log(b()); // dá: 1
```

Answer (score 16):

<strike>Apenas como curiosidade (já que o padrão que está valendo ainda é o da versão 5).</strike>

O [ECMAScript 6 (Codinome Harmony)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725142152/http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals) inclui <strike>uma [proposta de](https://web.archive.org/web/20160605084651/http://wiki.ecmascript.org:80/doku.php?id=harmony:parameter_default_values)</strike> sintaxe para parâmetros com valores padrão. Você já pode experimentar [a nova sintaxe no Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters). <strike>De acordo com a [Wikipedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20140517115053/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29) a data de lançamento esperada para o novo padrão é Dezembro de 2014</strike>:

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a*b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

---

***UPDATE***: Atualizando a resposta em Novembro de 2018. O [*ECMAScript 6*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), também conhecido como *ES2015* foi lançado em Junho de 2015 com suporte à sintaxe acima para *default function parameters*. Essa nova sintaxe é suportada em versões modernas dos principais navegadores, com exceção notável do Internet Explorer ([veja tabela de compatibilidade no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)).

Answer (score 12):

Não há uma forma de fazer isso de forma prática.

Entretanto, essa resposta não me agrada, e sabendo que javascript é uma linguagem tão dinâmica, resolvi usar um pouco do meu tempo para refletir, pesquisar e finalmente, juntando as peças criei um método para permitir indicar valores default de forma fácil.

Como usar:

```
var funcao = (function(x) { return x; }).WithDefaults([10]);
```

Ou então, um exemplo um pouco mais complexo, que é suportado pelo `WithDefaults`:

```
var myFunc = (function (a) {
    return a + arguments[1];
}).WithDefaults([, "y"]);
```

### Código do método `Function.prototype.WithDefaults`

```
(function () {
    var setDefaults = function (a, d) {
        var l = Math.max(a.length, d.length);
        var p = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
            p[i] = i >= a.length || typeof a[i] == 'undefined' ? d[i] : a[i];
        return p;
    }

    var copyProperties = function (to, from, defs) {
        to.innerFunction = from;
        to.toString = function () {
            var strDefs = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < defs.length; i++)
                strDefs += (i > 0 ? ", " : "")
                    + (typeof defs[i] != 'undefined' ? JSON.stringify(defs[i]) : "");

            return "(" + from.toString() + ").WithDefaults(["
                + strDefs + "])";
        };
        for (var key in from)
            to[key] = from[key];
        return to;
    }

    var fnCreators = {
        0: function (f, d, sd, cp) {
            return cp(function () {
                return f.apply(this, sd(arguments, d));
            }, f, d);
        },
        1: function (f, d, sd, cp) {
            return cp(function (p1) {
                return f.apply(this, sd(arguments, d));
            }, f, d);
        },
        2: function (f, d, sd, cp) {
            return cp(function (p1, p2) {
                return f.apply(this, sd(arguments, d));
            }, f, d);
        },
        3: function (f, d, sd, cp) {
            return cp(function (p1, p2, p3) {
                return f.apply(this, sd(arguments, d));
            }, f, d);
        }
    };

    function getFnCreator(numParams) {
        if (typeof fnCreators[numParams] != 'undefined')
            return fnCreators[numParams];

        var paramNames = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < numParams; i++) {
            paramNames[i] = "p" + (i + 1);
        }

        fnCreators[numParams] = new Function("f", "d", "sd", "cp",
            "return cp(function(" + paramNames.join(",") + ") {\
                return f.apply(this, sd(arguments, d));\
            }, f, d);");

        return fnCreators[numParams];
    }

    Function.prototype.WithDefaults = function (defs) {
        var creator = getFnCreator(this.length);
        return creator(this, defs, setDefaults, copyProperties);
    }
})();
```

### [Exemplo de uso do método `WithDefaults` no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/Ygwhy/2/)

Comment: Hey, ótimo seu código, o resto eu achei meio que uma gambiarra que pode, soou mais profissional o seu, nao devem ter se agradado pela extensão do código, mas este poderia ser inserido nos arquivos jquery.js do site e agir como uma funçao padrao.

Comment: Achei este https://gist.github.com/cjwainwright/4678359 que é bem mais simples e curto e simples, nao sei se vc que fez mas me cai muito bem, enfim parabéens!

Comment: @user3715916 Este gist não é meu... o código dessa resposta sim é meu. Existe um motivo para eu ter feito dessa forma: manter o length da função gerada. Para uma `fn = function(x,y)` => `fn.length = 2`. Para `fn2 = fn.WithDefaults([1,3])` => `fn2.length = 2`. Fiz isso para manter o máximo de informações originais iguais à função original. Note também que até o `toString` continua retornando a mesma coisa.

Comment: Atualizei o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ygwhy/3/) para comparar a minha solução com a do gist que você indicou.

Answer (score 10):

Há algumas maneiras, mas eu prefiro da seguinte forma:

```
function func(x){
    x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 10;
    return x;
}
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kuQn/)

Answer (score 8):

Dessa forma:

```
function Retorno(x){
    if(x == 0)
        return x;

    x = x || 10; // Valor de x caso existir ou 10 que é o padrão
    return x;
}
```

Recomendo a leitura [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5053/3999) do **Miguel Angelo** que explica melhor o funcionamento do `||`(ou) como operador de coalescência em Javascript.

Comment: Testando com 0 neste caso, o valor retornado é 15, o que não deveria ocorrer.

Comment: Isso acontece porque no Javascript 0 é tratado como false, então adicionei um if caso o valor for zero retornar o x