# Objeto como parâmetro numa função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, parâmetros

Procurei em diversos lugares sobre o uso de objeto como parâmetro numa função, mas somente encontrei [nesse site](http://www.brunonardini.com.br/desenv-front-end/usando-objeto-como-parametro-no-javascript), porém não me senti a vontade com essa estrutura. qual a melhor forma de por um objeto como parâmetro de uma função JavaScript e definir um valor padrão?

Ex:

```
function teste(options) {
   options = (typeof options !== "object") ? {} : options;
   options.nome = options.nome || 'João';
   options.idade = options.idade || 20 ;
   console.log(options);
};
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como colocar argumentos default (padrão) em uma função em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15350/como-colocar-argumentos-default-padr%c3%a3o-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript)

Comment: Realmente é bem semelhante, somente com o diferencial de estar usando objetos, que a partir daqueles exemplos é possível adapta-los.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta que você encontrou parece adequada. Como o javascript não utiliza tipos para os parâmetros das funções, você vai precisar validar se o parâmetro passado é realmente um objeto:

```
options = (typeof options !== "object") ? {} : options;
```

Caso um outro tipo de variável for passada, ele cria um objeto vazio.
Um outro problema é caso o objeto passado não tenha os atributos desejados. Isso explica as seguintes linhas:

```
options.nome = options.nome || 'João';
options.idade = options.idade || 20 ;
```

Uma forma mais adequada de resolver isso é utilizar o conceito de classes, de forma que você possa validar se o objeto passado é uma instancia da classe desejada. Segue um exemplo:

```
//método construtor da classe
var Pessoa = function(nome, idade){
    //this se refere ao objeto que está sendo instanciado
    this.nome = nome || 'João';
    this.idade = idade || 20 ;
}

function teste(pessoa){
    pessoa = pessoa instanceof Pessoa ? pessoa : new Pessoa;
    console.log(pessoa);
}
```

Você pode fazer mais validações a respeito dos argumentos passados para a construção do objeto Pessoa, como por exemplo:

```
var Pessoa = function(nome, idade){
    if(typeof nome != 'string' || nome.length < 3){
        this.nome = 'João';
    }else{
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    if(isNaN(idade) || idade < 0){
        this.idade = 20 ;
    }else{
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

Isso te permite um maior controle em relação aos objetos criados. Mas tenha em mente que isso não proíbe que os atributos do objeto pessoa sejam alterados após sua construção, como por exemplo:

```
var jose = new Pessoa("José",35);
jose.nome = 0;
```

Para evitar esse tipo de comportamento, precisamos de ainda mais complexidade no código. Recomendo que você leia esse excelente artigo da Mozzila à respeito de orientação à objetos no Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Existe alguma outra forma de atribuir um valor padrão diferente de "options.nome = options.nome || 'João';" ?

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo utilizando classe e objetos como parâmetro?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Exatamente isso, somente imaginei que havia uma forma de fazer isso sem usar condicionais e etc, mas para isso tenho que continuar estudando