# Qual o significado do operador "??"

Tags: c#, .net, operadores

Estava olhando uns códigos e me deparei com o operador `??`:

```
static int? GetNullableInt()
{
    return null;
}
```

`int y = x ?? -1;`

Qual a diferença do primeiro código para o segundo?

Comment: Relacionado: [Existe no javascript um operador de coalescência nula?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5052/)

Comment: Tem algo específico que queira saber sobre o primeiro código?

Comment: somente o significado do operador "?"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ele é chamado de [*null-coalescing*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Em alguns contextos ele é chamado de operador "Elvis".

Se o primeiro operando é nulo, o resultado da expressão será o segundo operando. Caso contrário o resultado será o primeiro operando.

```
int y = x ?? -1;
```

é o mesmo que fazer:

```
int y = (x == null) ? -1 : x;
```

Se você tem um valor que pode, de forma correta e interessante, substituir um valor nulo que provavelmente causaria um problema no uso, é uma forma simples de realizar a substituição.

[Artigo na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator).

## `int?`

Os dois códigos fazem coisas completamente diferentes, não dá para compará-los. O primeiro apenas retorna um nulo, o que provavelmente tem algum motivo muito específico no código encontrado. O que tem nele de diferente é o `int?`.

Este é um tipo. O nome completo do tipo é `int?` (lê-se "int anulável"). Isto é usado apenas em [tipos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Estes tipos são criados como [`structs`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101), e não podem ter um valor nulo, já que nulo é apenas uma referência para um local inválido da memória (em geral 0). Então estes tipos foram criados para permitir que tipos por valor tenham um nulo.

Estes tipos são chamados de *nullable types* ou tipos anuláveis. No fundo é uma `struct` composta basicamente por dois membros, o valor do tipo, no caso um `int` e um campo `bool` para dizer se ele é nulo ou não. Se for nulo, o valor não deve ser lido.

Este tipos na verdade são obtidos com a classe [`Nullable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1). Então `int?` é apenas um açúcar sintático para `Nullable<int>`.

## Complemento

Em C# 6 existe também o `?.` (*null-propagating*). Ele será usado para decidir se o próximo operando será avaliado ou não. Por exemplo:

```
x.ExecuteAlgo();
```

resultará em uma exceção se `x` for nulo. Porém se usar o novo operador o método simplesmente não será executado. Isto é útil em alguns cenários em que você não quer que algo seja executado, se o objeto estiver em um estado inválido por nulidade:

```
x?.ExecuteAlgo();
```

Executará o método somente se o objeto `x` estiver inicializado corretamente. Este código é o mesmo que fazer:

```
if (x != null)
    x.ExecuteAlgo();
```

Um exemplo mais complexo:

```
x?.y?.z;
```

é equivalente a isto:

```
(x == null ? null : (x.y == null ? null : x.y.z))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/NullCoalescing.cs).

Para testar isto [baixe o Visual Studio 2015](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou superior que conta com o novo compilador e o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Saiba mais [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101).

Comment: Esse `null-propagating` é seria uma mão na roda se tivesse em php :(

Comment: Muito bom os exemplos