# Habilitar/Desabilitar Button de acordo com valor Checkbox em um DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Um formulário em uma aplicação `Windows Forms` com `C#` exibe um `DataGridView` com `Checkbox`.
Quando um dos `Checkbox` for marcado quero habilitar um determinado botão.
Se nenhum `Checkbox` for marcado quero desabilitar.

Tente assim:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool marcado = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["chk"];
        if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
        {
            marcado = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (marcado)
        button1.Enabled = true;
    else
        button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

E não funcionou.

Tentei usar no `CellValueChanged` e também não esta funcionando.

Como resolver este problema.

Comment: estou sem o Visual Studio para testar, mas tente alterar `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["chk"];` para `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["chk"];`, se der certo eu crio uma resposta!

Comment: @Mateus Ainda não funcionou. O valores `chk.Value` e `chk.TrueValue` estao com `Value` = `null`. Acho que estou usando no método errado. Mas valeu a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o evento `CellValueChanged` desse jeito:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // se a célula alterada for a célula de interesse (1.)
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("chk"))
    {
        bool marcado = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["chk"]; // (2.)
            // se a célula estiver marcada
            if ((bool)(chk.Value ?? false) == true) // (3.) e (4.)
            {
                marcado = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (marcado)
            button1.Enabled = true;
        else
            button1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Seguem alguns pontos de atenção:

1. Utilizei um `if` antes de verificar os valores das `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` para evitar que a verificação ocorra em todas as colunas.
2. Conforme falei nos comentários, foi necessário alterar `dataGridView1.CurrentRow` para `row`, pois senão seu `for` não iria percorrer todas as linhas, mas sim, somente a linha corrente (referente a célula alterada).
3. O `??` serve para verificar se operador a esquerda dele é nulo, caso seja, retorna o valor da direita, senão, retorna o valor da esquerda, para saber mais veja [Qual o significado do operador "??"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44133).
4. A propriedade `TrueValue` deve ser utilizada de outra forma, como não sei exatamente como você está usando o `DataGridView`, preferi não utilizá-la, mas você poder ver um exemplo [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell.truevalue(v=vs.90).aspx).

Não sei exatamente qual o volume de dados você irá trabalhar, mas fazer esse `for` toda vez que uma célula for marcada/desmarcada, provavelmente você não terá um bom desempenho, pensei em outra solução, talvez seja necessário que você a melhore, porém já serve como ponto de partida.

Crie uma variável global `private int numeroCelulasMarcadas = 0;`, essa variável vai servir como um contador de células marcadas, no evento `RowsAdded` do `DataGridView`, faça assim:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk =
        (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["chk"];

    if ((bool)(chk.Value ?? false) == true)
    {
        numeroCelulasMarcadas++;
    }
}
```

Agora no evento `CellValueChanged` coloque isso:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // se a célula alterada for a célula de interesse
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("chk"))
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = 
            (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["chk"];

        if ((bool)chk.Value == true)
        {
            numeroCelulasMarcadas++;
        }
        else
        {
            numeroCelulasMarcadas--;
        }

        if (numeroCelulasMarcadas == 0)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Lembre-se que essa solução que passei por último é um ponto de partida, pode ser que seja necessário ajustar alguma coisa para funcionar corretamento no contexto da sua aplicação.

Comment: O post tem informações importantes, porém ainda não funcionou. Usando qualquer umas das opções de código o método `CellValueChanged` ao marca o primeiro `CheckBox` ele não é disparado. Nem estou preocupado com a performance a principio, pois seria poucos registros.

Comment: @Jota, após alterar o valor da célula, você tentou pressionar `ENTER` ou sair da célula? Pois testei várias vezes antes de postar a resposta e funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Eu não sabia que tinha de teclar `Enter`, realmente funciona. O problema é que o usuário não quer teclar o `Enter`. kkkk Quebrando a cabeça e com o que você postou, consegui uma solução que funciona somente com o click usando o `CellContentClick` e `CellContentDoubleClick`. Mas valeu a ajuda e o conhecimento compartilhado.

Comment: você pode aceitar a resposta se acha que te ajudei a atingir o objetivo da pergunta ou pode criar e aceitar sua própria resposta com a solução que você encontrou, detalhando como você fez.

Comment: As duas soluções podem ser consideradas corretas. kkk Vou ver o que faço. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A solução que o Mateus propôs funciona, mas é preciso pressionar a tecla `Enter`, no meu caso o usuário queria somente clicar no `CheckBox`, então usei a seguinte solução:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("chk"))
    {
        ManipulaBotao();
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("chk"))
    {
        ManipulaBotao();
    }
}

private void ManipulaBotao()
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(dr.Cells["chk"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim somente clicando no `CheckBox` o controle é habilitado/desabilitado.

Vale ressaltar que no meu caso o número de linhas é pequeno então não afeta a performance, como foi muito bem lembrado no post do Mateus.

Note o uso do método `CellContentDoubleClick`, senão não funciona como o esperado.

Comment: o principal fator para ter funcionado é a propriedade `EditedFormattedValue`, pois havia tentado nesse evento também, mas utilizando a propriedade `Value`, que não retornava o valor atual e sim o que estava quando entrou na célula.