# Receber int anulável em Razor (@Html.TextboxFor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho um objeto `Carro` e tenho uma propriedade do tipo inteiro e anulável chamada `AnoInspecao`. Na hora de criar, eu consigo criar um objeto carro com o ano de inspeção nulo (sem digitar nada) e persistir no banco normalmente.

```
var carro = new Carro()
{
   carro.AnoInspecao = null;
   carro.Nome = "meuCarro"
}
```

Na hora de editar (*View*), eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
@Html.TexboxFor(model => model.AnoInspecao)
```

Porém não funciona, pois o `Textbox` não aceita nulo, gerando assim uma `Exception`.

Como posso tratar isso?

Comment: Só gera exceção quando o `AnoInspecao` é nulo, certo?

Comment: Exatamente @jbueno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra forma é usando o seguinte:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AnoInspecao, new { Value = "", @type = "number" })
```

Tirando o `@type`, essa solução funciona pra tudo que for `Nullable`.

Comment: Deu certo agora @Cigano. Reiniciei o VS e funciou lindamente rs. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Simples, não passe `null` para o `TextBox`.

```
@Html.TexboxFor(model => model.AnoInspecao ?? "")
```

ou

```
@Html.TexboxFor(model => model.AnoInspecao != null ? model.AnoInspecao.ToString() : "")
```

O operador **??** é chamado de *null-coalescing*. Ele valida o que tem do lado esquerdo e, se for `null` faz com que o valor enviado seja o que vem do lado direito.

Relacionado: [Qual o significado do operador "??"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44133/qual-o-significado-do-operador/44134#44134)

Comment: O problema é que o AnoInspecao é um inteiro. Com o null-coalescing  transformaria em uma string, resultando em uma incompatibilidade de dados.

Comment: Podes passar 0 então, ou não serve?

Comment: O operador ?? não pode ser aplicado para números inteiros.

Comment: Não serve rs. Preciso deixar o campo vazio.

Comment: Veja a outra alternativa.

Comment: Continua dando exception :(

Comment: Por óbvio. Eu usei `==` ao invés de `!=`. Troque isso que vai dar certo

Comment: Tinha corrigido. Ainda assim não deu certo. Ele retorna o seguinte: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: Você tentou a solução do Cigano?

Comment: A dele resolveu. Tive que reiniciar o VS, pode ter bugado alguma coisa. Muito obrigado pela ajudo @jbueno. Abs